# How can I see past versions of a Google sheet when I update it via the API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am updating a Google sheet via the api, Python code snippet that I'm using here (this works fine):

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = (
    sheet.values()
    .update(
      spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range="Sheet1!A1:A4",
      valueInputOption='RAW',
      body=dict(
        majorDimension='COLUMNS',
        values= [
          ["Item 3", "Wheel 3", "Door 3", "Engine 3"]
        ]          
      )
    ).execute()
)
```

But when I call that repeatedly (with different values, so it *is* changing the sheet), and I look at the version history for the sheet, there are no versions. How can I make it so I can see all the past versions that I've updated?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, is this information useful? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions/list

Comment: When I edit a sheet in the UI, I see that my changes are logged in the "revision history", and I can navigate past to previous versions. I would like each api call to behave as though I have edited the sheet in the UI, and see those revisions in the history of the sheet when I go look at it. Does that make sense?